# Ubuntu 14.04 using 100% swap space, with more than 40GB free memory, why?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, swap

I'm a bit at a loss trying to figure out why this would be the case. Can anyone provide some helpful ideas on troubleshooting this?

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         50314      27726      22587      21255         82      21549
-/+ buffers/cache:       6094      44219
Swap:         4091       4091          0
```

The system's swappiness is set to 0, though:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness 
0
```

Why is this the case? How can I determine why this is happening? I'd expect with the swappiness set to 0, that the system's swap would never be used. Is this an incorrect assumption on my part?

Comment: It might simply be that the memory usage was higher and pages got swapped out at that time. If the content of those pages haven't been accessed since then, they may as well stay on swap.

Comment: Do you have any historical data at all?  Do you have atsar installed perhaps?  Or something else that you can use to look back over the last few hours/days and see when the usage started?  Maybe then you could associate it with some specific task.